# Using the index of a multidimensional array parameter for a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem and don't find any solution.

```
    for index, value in numpy.ndenumerate(re):
        re[index] += rec[(index)]
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. The function looks like this:

```
def rec(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3):
```

The size of the index does fit to the number of parameters for the function. I want to keep it as generell as possible, thus

```
for [x1][x2][x3][y1][y2][y3][z1][z2][z3], value in numpy.ndenumerate(re):
        re[index] += rec[(index)]
```

doesn't help me. Do u have any idea?

Comment: That's not a problem description, it's some code, and "this doesn't work" is not an explanation.  Please read up on how to construct a [mcve].

Comment: I just want to use as parameters for a function the index value of an multidimensional numpy.array.

Comment: Use `np.meshgrid` for that. You  construct vectors for each dimension first `x=np.arange(0,1,0.01)` etc., then `np.meshgrid` will generate an n-dimensional grid, that you can use as input you a `ufunc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`This doesn't work unfortunately` is not the right way to describe your problem.  You need to tell us something of the error that you get.

But my guess it has something to do with `rec` not being indexable, or have a `__getitem__` method.

You define a function with lots of arguments:

```
def rec(x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3):
    ....
```

You then have to call it as a function.  It is not a list or array.

```
rec(1,2,3,....) # should work
```

or

```
index = (1,2,3,...)
rec(*index)
```

If so, then the following might work:

```
for index, value in numpy.ndenumerate(re):
        re[index] += rec(*index)
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that was actually the solutions which I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

A 2D example (Ipython notebook)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p # just for visualization
%matplotlib inline

x=np.arange(0,1,0.01)  # <-- give ranges to your parameters
y=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x,y)   # <--- generate the n-dimensional indeces

zv= np.sin(xv + 3* yv)  # <-- this is the ufunc, look ma: no for loops

p.imshow(zv,aspect ='1')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) That helped

Comment: Sorry, the other solution just helped more :D